# Bash merging files (csv, tsv, txt :fixed-width) problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, newline

Goal : create a single csv file named "consolidate_data" by combining data from

- csv_data.csv : columns 1 to 4 from "vehicle-data.csv"

> ```
> 1,Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021,125094,car,2,VC965
>
> 2,Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021,174434,car,2,VC965
>
> 3,Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021,8538286,car,2,VC965
> ```

- tsv_data.csv : columns 5 to 7 from "tollplaza-data.tsv"

> ```
> 1       Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021        125094  car     2       4856    PC7C042B7
>
> 2       Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021        174434  car     2       4154    PC2C2EF9E
>
> 3       Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021        8538286 car     2       4070    PCEECA8B2
> ```

- fixed_width_data.csv : the two last columns from "payment-data.txt"

> ```
>  1 Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021 125094     4856 PC7C042B7 PTE VC965
>  2 Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021 174434     4154 PC2C2EF9E PTP VC965
>  3 Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021 8538286    4070 PCEECA8B2 PTE VC965
> ```

What I tried so far:

```
cut -d"," -f1-4 vehicle-data.csv > csv_data.csv
tr "\\t" "," < tollplaza-data.tsv | cut -d',' -f5-7  > tsv_data.csv
cut -c59-68 payment-data.txt | tr " " "," > fixed_width_data.csv
paste -d',' csv_data.csv tsv_data.csv fixed_width_data.csv > consolidate_data.csv
```

the order of files in the paste fulfil the order of columns wanted in "consolidate_data" file

The Problem (see picture) is that i got new lines for the last two columns in "consolidate_data", I suspect the existence of the "newline" character in the tsv file but I cant see it.

#The_result_I_got :

```
1,Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021,125094,car,2,4856,PC7C042B7
,PTE,VC965
2,Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021,174434,car,2,4154,PC2C2EF9E
,PTP,VC965
3,Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021,8538286,car,2,4070,PCEECA8B2
,PTE,VC965
4,Mon Aug  2 18:23:45 2021,5521221,car,2,4095,PC3E1512A
,PTP,VC965
5,Thu Jul 29 22:44:20 2021,3267767,car,2,4135,PCC943ECD
,PTE,VC965
6,Sat Aug 14 03:57:47 2021,8411850,car,2,4680,PCC422F4D
,PTE,VC965
.
.
.
10000,Mon Aug  9 22:56:50 2021,4833266,car,2,4260,PC1A4796C,PTE,VC965
```

-->I noticed that last line was in the wanted format

#The_result_wanted:

```
1,Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021,125094,car,2,4856,PC7C042B7,PTE,VC965
2,Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021,174434,car,2,4154,PC2C2EF9E,PTP,VC965
3,Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021,8538286,car,2,4070,PCEECA8B2,PTE,VC965
4,Mon Aug  2 18:23:45 2021,5521221,car,2,4095,PC3E1512A,PTP,VC965
5,Thu Jul 29 22:44:20 2021,3267767,car,2,4135,PCC943ECD,PTE,VC965
6,Sat Aug 14 03:57:47 2021,8411850,car,2,4680,PCC422F4D,PTE,VC965
7,Thu Aug 12 03:41:22 2021,6064250,car,2,4702,PCDBC3AC9,PTE,VC965
8,Sun Aug 22 10:29:58 2021,6871937,van,2,4592,PC627AA14,PTE,VCD2F
9,Fri Aug  6 14:23:08 2021,2055930,car,2,4100,PCC6DD8D5,PTP,VC965
```

You can find data in this [enter link description here](https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DB0250EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Final%20Assignment/tolldata.tgz)

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Please post your input data, result, and desired result as text embedding in your question, not with pictures or links.

Comment: Your tsv file has DOS line endings (CR+LF). Try to append `tr -d '\r'` to the pipeline to generate `tsv_data.csv`.

Comment: Run `dos2unix <FILE>` to remove the DOS line endings on files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is resolved by deliting the '\r' as suggested by @tshiono.

Comment: the issue is resolved by runing the dos2unix on the file too as suggested by @Nic3500. Thank you all for drawing my attention to this endings issue. Have a nice day